# Get specific value from string of text in Hive

Tags: hive, hiveql

I need to get the value `5` from the string of text below in a Hive Table. For some reason the floor and split functions I used can get values "0" and "3" but i don't know what to do to get the first value in front of the first "/":

```
Column name: logsummary
**Record:5/0/3/0/4/4/143504**

Select 
floor(split(logsummary, '[/]')[1]) as draws,
floor(split(logsummary, '[/]')[2]) as losses
from table A
```

Answer (score 0):

Use 0 value instead of 1 then you will get 5 value

```
hive> Select floor(split('5/0/3/0/4/4/143504', '[/]')[0]) as draws;
    +--------+--+
    | draws  |
    +--------+--+
    | 5      |
    +--------+--+
```

Below statement demonstrates results of floor(0,1,2) from your Record

```
hive> Select floor(split('5/0/3/0/4/4/143504', '[/]')[0]) as draws,floor(split('5/0/3/0/4/4/143504', '[/]')[1]),floor(split('5/0/3/0/4/4/143504', '[/]')[2]) losses;
+--------+------+---------+--+
| draws  | _c1  | losses  |
+--------+------+---------+--+
| 5      | 0    | 3       |
+--------+------+---------+--+
```

Answer (score 0):

The Hive `split()` function takes two parameters `(string, regex pattern)`, and splits the `string` as per the `regex`. The splits will be returned in an array.

Each split can be accessed via an array index. You need 5, which is available at index 0.

Hence, the query should be:

```
Select 
floor(split('5/0/3/0/4/4/143504', '[/]')[0]) as draws,
floor(split('5/0/3/0/4/4/143504', '[/]')[1]) as losses;

--Output:
draws   losses
5       0
```

Just to expand on this example, these are all the splits:

```
Select 
floor(split('5/0/3/0/4/4/143504', '[/]')[0]) as e0,
floor(split('5/0/3/0/4/4/143504', '[/]')[1]) as e1,
floor(split('5/0/3/0/4/4/143504', '[/]')[2]) as e2,
floor(split('5/0/3/0/4/4/143504', '[/]')[3]) as e3,
floor(split('5/0/3/0/4/4/143504', '[/]')[4]) as e4,
floor(split('5/0/3/0/4/4/143504', '[/]')[5]) as e5,
floor(split('5/0/3/0/4/4/143504', '[/]')[6]) as e6;

--Output
e0  e1  e2  e3  e4  e5  e6
5   0   3   0   4   4   143504
```